# scrapy use mongodb to store info

Tags: mongodb, scrapy

I'm writing a web spider to get user info on stack overflow. And I'm trying to store the info using mongodb. 
here is the code for my web spider, which works fine:

```
class webSpider(Spider):
    name = "user_spider1"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = []
def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1,2):
        self.start_urls.append(  "http://stackoverflow.com/users?page="+ str(i)+"&tab=reputation&filter=week")
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

def parse(self, response):

    htmlTxt = response.body
    baseDomain = etree.HTML(htmlTxt)

    userSubUrl = baseDomain.xpath('//div[@class="user-details"]/a/@href')
    baseUrl = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
    for subUrl in userSubUrl:


        yield Request(baseUrl+subUrl,callback=self.parse_userinfo)

def parse_userinfo(self,response):
    htmlTxt = response.body
    infoDomain = etree.HTML(htmlTxt)

    item['user_name'] = stringprocessor(str(infoDomain.xpath('//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()[1]')))
    item['user_location'] = stringprocessor(str(infoDomain.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled"]/li[1]/text()[2]')))
    item['user_reputation'] = stringprocessor(str(infoDomain.xpath('//div[@class="reputation"]/text()[1]')))
    tags = infoDomain.xpath('//div[@class="tag-container row"]/div/a[@class="post-tag"]/text()')

    item['user_tags'] = tags
    yield item
```

and here is my pipeline file and settings, which is probably wrong:

```
import pymongo


from scrapy import log
from scrapy.conf import settings

class Spider1Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):

        connection = pymongo.Connection(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]

        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg('Item written to MongoDB database ',level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
        return item
```

settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'test1'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['test1.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'test1.spiders'


ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['test1.pipelines.Spider1Pipeline',]

MONGODB_SERVER='localhost'
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_DB='test1'
MONGODB_COLLECTION='user_info'
```

the error I get is like this:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I'm really confused here. Plz help me out here.

Comment: You should not be doing that, it goes against stackoverflow [TOS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline looks ok. Your spider is somewhat weird. Here's a version that works a bit better:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "user_spider1"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1,2):
            self.start_urls.append(  "http://stackoverflow.com/users?page="+ str(i)+"&tab=reputation&filter=week")
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        userSubUrl = response.xpath('//div[@class="user-details"]/a/@href').extract()
        baseUrl = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
        for subUrl in userSubUrl:
            yield Request(baseUrl+subUrl, callback=self.parse_userinfo)

    def parse_userinfo(self,response):
        item = {}

        stringprocessor = lambda x: x
        item['user_name'] = stringprocessor(str(response.xpath('//h2[@class="user-card-name"]/text()[1]').extract_first()))
        item['user_location'] = stringprocessor(str(response.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled"]/li[1]/text()[2]').extract_first()))
        item['user_reputation'] = stringprocessor(str(response.xpath('//div[@class="reputation"]/text()[1]').extract_first()))
        tags = response.xpath('//div[@class="tag-container row"]/div/a[@class="post-tag"]/text()').extract_first()

        item['user_tags'] = tags
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
Replace your list

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['test1.pipelines.Spider1Pipeline',]
```

by a dict

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'test1.pipelines.Spider1Pipeline':300}
```

*"The integer values you assign to classes in this setting determine the order they run in- items go through pipelines from order number low to high. It’s customary to define these numbers in the 0-1000 range."*
source: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component